# Extract part of text from a URL in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on extracting a part of the URL to another column. Here are 2 URLs -

```
http://learn.reg.edu/degree-programs/religion-theology/?bm_source=facebook&bm_medium=ppc&bm_campaign_id=6086055048219&bm_adset_id=6086055734819&bm_ad_id=6094109509819&bm_placement=Facebook_Mobile_Feed   

http://learn.regent.edu/home-2/?persist=1&bm_placement=an&bm_ad_id=%7B%7Bad.id%7D%7D&bm_adset_id=%7B%7Badset.id%7D%7D&bm_campaign_id=%7B%7Bcampaign.id%7D%7D&bm_campaign=rm&bm_medium=ppc&bm_source=facebook
```

So I wish to pull out text after "bm_placement=" and whatever it says (like in the above two urls, url 1 has "Facebook_Mobile_Feed" and url 2 has "an")

I am using this formula -

```
=RIGHT(ES16760,LEN(ES16760)-(FIND("bm_placement=",ES16760,1) +12))
```

It works fine for the first URL but for the second one, it pulls out everything after "an" which I do not want. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want everything after in all cases how do you determine when stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MID with a lot of FINDs:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("bm_placement=",A1)+ LEN("bm_placement="),FIND("&",A1&"&",FIND("bm_placement=",A1))-(FIND("bm_placement=",A1)+ LEN("bm_placement=")))
```

[image]

Comment: I thought it would take innumerable FINDs. Thank you for the help! This works.