# Excel - Trimming Part of the URL to use as a title in the Hyperlink Function

Tags: google-sheets, url

I'm putting together a spreadsheet of PlayStation Store URLs in Google Docs, I need to grab the Title ID (CUSA), the Title Number (00473) and what I'm assuming is the package name? (LBP3GAME00000001) from the URL to use as a title in the `=HYPERLINK()` function, Example URL (https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP9000-CUSA00473_00-LBP3GAME00000001)

What I am attempting to format the URL as: [CUSA00473 - LBP3GAME00000001](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP9000-CUSA00473_00-LBP3GAME00000001)

(I do already have a cell with the string "UP9000-CUSA00473_00-LBP3GAME00000001" already in my sheet)

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879341/extract-part-of-text-from-a-url-in-excel) where someone was using =MID() to extract text located after `bm_placement=`, would this work for my current situation and would someone be able to explain it to me please? Thanks.

Comment: Would the string always follow the same pattern? If so, try: `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^.*?-(.*?)_\d*","$1")`

Comment: The URL format always stays the same, the only thing that differs is the string, typing that into a Cell displays the link, am I supposed to put the regexreplace in the hyperlink function or do `=HYPERLINK(A1, A2)` where A1 is the link and A2 is the regexreplace?

Comment: The latter would be true @Aeywoo

Comment: I tried doing that, the end result was the same URL that A1 and A2 were displaying.

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I_tAdyvLTOk0vVGFMYsK4pQhRINA0Me1MxAhIUxTqQg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Right so you didn't use the regex on the cell with the smaller string as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: I see that now, thanks. How do I mark one of these comments as the solution?

Comment: I gave an answer down below. Hopefully all works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following on your source link:

```
=HYPERLINK(B1,REGEXREPLACE(B1,"^.*-([^_]+)_\d+","$1"))
```

Comment: If I wanted to add a space before and after the hyphen would I just add quotation marks with the spaces?

Comment: I suppose you can use `REGEXREPLACE(B1,"^.*-([^_]+)_\d+-","$1 - ")` @Aeywoo